# How to do I connect from my cmd to snowflake account using snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect using snowsql from cmd but it fails every time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBtAS.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images add all information directly to your question. Please update your question with the full snowsql command you are running and if applicable, the relevant section from your config file - obfuscating usernames, passwords, etc obviously

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is that the account name looks incorrect. It should have the region details where it is deployed, except for the case when it is deployed on **US West (Oregon)** region and should not be including "snowflakecomputing.com"

For eg: if the actual URL which you use from browser to access SF UI is abcd.region.snowflakecomputing.com, then account name to be used for connecting from Snowsql would be : **abcd.region**

If not, then get the exact identifier from the following doc link for specific regions: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html

and try again connecting from SnowSQL.